# Google Sheets - Make a copy of a column into itself

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Table to represent what is wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7gJj.png)

Is there any way to dynamically turn the left column into the right one?

Comment: Although the picture explains, Kindly explain your question in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A1:A5&"",2)),"")))
```

Comment: Interesting & visually appealing solution

Comment: @Tom What can I say?  It's `Halloween themed `. Yours is shorter and better though.

Comment: This formula is genius!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(int((row(B:B)+1)/2),{row(A:A),A:A},2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Column you want to move, hover over it and when a hand cursor appears drag it to where you want it to go.

Comment: I want a formula to automatically take the first column, do what is in the picture linked, and then copy it.